# Animate effect using angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-animate

Is there any animate method in angular.

I have a button which shows the container on click, the transition should be smooth and slow.

This is what I have tried, I dint tried any animate method.

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">{{toggleText}}</button>
<div class="box on" ng-show="toggle" ng-animate="'box'">
    Hai I am Hiding Hai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am HidingHai I am Hiding....
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function () {

})

app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.toggle = true;

    $scope.$watch('toggle', function(){
        $scope.toggleText = $scope.toggle ? 'Toggle!' : 'some text';
    })
})
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljrpd/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a module [ng-animate](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations).

And a first example in documentation does exactly what you are trying to achieve.